# How to show a tooltip on a datatable cell and how to fill data in tabular format in the tooltip?

Tags: datatables

Below is my datatable creation code. on the 'Show Details' column I need to show a tooltip. I have written below for that cell but I am facing below two problems.

1. Value from render function is overrding my cell´s value. So 'Show
   Details' is getting replaced by value from render function.
2. Values which I am getting from ajaxSource, I need to show in
   tabular format in the tooltip. Below is my code:

**Code**

```
function testDataTable() {

             var columnIndex=$('#columnIndex').val();

             var sortBy=$('#sortBy').val();

             var resultPerPage=$('#resultPerPage').val();

          if(columnIndex=='' || sortBy==''){
                  resultPerPage=20;
                  columnIndex=0;
                  sortBy="desc";
              }

            testDataTable= $('#testDataTable').dataTable({
                "bProcesing" : true,
                "bServerSide" : true,
                "sort" : "position",
                "destroy" : true,
                "processing" : true,
                "bFilter" : false,
                "bLenthChange" : false,
                "iDisplayLength" : 4,
                "sAjaxSource" : "getRulesDetails.act",
                "order" : [ [ columnIndex, sortBy ] ],
                "pageLength" : Number(resultPerPage),
                "columnDefs": [
                                { "orderable": false, "targets":[3, 4] }
                            ],
                            "aoColumns" : [
                                           {
                                               "mData" : "crId"                                    
                                           },
                                           {
                                                "mData" : "crNo"

                                           }, 
                                           {
                                               "mData" : "sbNo"

                                           },
                                           {
                                               "mData" : "matchType"

                                           },
                                           {
                                               "mData" : null,
                                               "defaultContent": 'Show Details',
                                               "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                                    return '<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Testing"></span>';
                                                }
                                           }

                       ],
}

} );
            }
```